# API google Map with many Smartphones Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Can i use my API google Map in many Smartphone Android ? or other say

Can i use my API google Map in Commercial and publicity my applications ?

**_ _ _ _ in fact, i have an API Google Map to load Map(Google Map) and i developper something in this Map.

 _ _ _ Now, i would like to publicity my application or commercialize this application ? in FRANCE, ITALY**

Thanks very much !

Comment: Please revise this question to be : 1 - A single question and 2 - for clarity. It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I would like to know, i can use my API google Map in Commercial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i use my API google Map in many Smartphone Android ?

Many Android phones have Google Maps. Not all Android phones have Google Maps. The vast majority of Android phones that legally have the Android Market have Google Maps.

> Can i use my API google Map in Commercial and publicity my applications ?

I do not know what this means. There are terms of service for using the Google Maps add-on for Android in your application -- you should have qualified legal counsel review that agreement. This is StackOverflow -- we are not experts in the law, particularly for whatever country you happen to reside in.

That being said, many Android applications are successfully and legally using Google Maps.

Comment: _ _ _in fact, i have an API Google Map to load Map(Google Map) and i developper something in this Map.                                     _ _ _ Now, i would like to publicity my application or commercialize this application ? in FRANCE, ITALY

Comment: @DO Ngoc Tuan: There are terms of service for using the Google Maps add-on for Android in your application -- you should have qualified legal counsel review that agreement. This is StackOverflow -- we are not experts in the law, particularly for whatever country you happen to reside in.

Comment: yes, thanks your instruction, CommonsWare . but in my opinion, it is useful for me and many people :)

Comment: I have just been tested with other Smartphone Android ! It is good :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to Commercial or publicity your application then you must need to Certificated API key for MapView. just change your api key with Certificated instead of old API key.

I hope it will be work.

Comment: "Note that, when you are ready to publish your application, you must get a Maps API Key that is based on the certificate that you will use to sign the application for release. You must then change the Maps API Key strings referenced by all of your MapView elements, so that they reference the new Key."